# How to escape characters in Atlassian Stash markdown

Tags: git, escaping, bitbucket-server

I am using git stash.

How can I escape the single and double quote characters in Stash ?

I have a readme.md file which has text like `git commit -m "comment"`

but it shows up as `git commit  �m �comment�`

I have tried using the `\` to escape these characters but that results in

```
git commit \�m \�comment�
```

Please help.

Comment: It seems to me that this is could be a problem with the encoding of the file or the git environment as in anycase the double quote characters shows up as junk

Comment: What command are you executing in order for git to pick up these statements from readme.md file ?
Are you using > git commit -f readme.md ?

Comment: Can you check the value of "commitencoding" in .git/config file ?

Comment: thanks Dinesh,
i am using the ususal git commit command that i use for commiting anything else. also, here are the contents of my config file
[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 symlinks = false
 ignorecase = true
 hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
 url = http://mkmkm/mkmkm/llplp.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/master

Comment: i do not see a commitencoding parameter

Comment: are you talking about the i18n.commitEncoding ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88028/discussion-between-dinesh-chitlangia-and-user2334092).

Comment: thanks but i cant use cant right now from my office.

Comment: Ok no problem. Yes I am talking about i18n.commitEncoding.

Comment: i dont have that property set in my config. should i add a line to my config like
i18n.commitEncoding = utf-8

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: unfortunately, that did not work. it had no effect

Comment: Can you show the exact command that you execute for readme.md file ?

Comment: i just do

git add

this shows that i have added the updated readme. then i do

git commit -m "some comment"

then finally

git push origin master

Comment: You can replace double quotes by single quote. So try with > git comment -m 'some comment'

Comment: wait, i think i did not specify the problem correctly. i have text in my readme which looks like

git commit -m "comment"

i am not having a problem with the git commit command\

Comment: Yes, this is what I understood initially and was asking you the command which you use to execute statements written in readme.md file. Just replace the double quotes with single quote in the file.

Comment: thanks but still does not work. single quotes show up as �
also how should i escape the dash or minus sign

Comment: This is definitely an issue with the either the file encoding or the encoding for the git environment. It could also be that the double quote may be from a different character set, although it may look similar to double quote but might have been encoded differently.
I just tried it myself and the double quote went through successfully.

Comment: thanks for your help Dinesh. i think i found the answer

Comment: I think Dinesh is correct, hyphens and double quotes should just work. If you used a text editor that replaced them with fancy en-dash or em-dashes, or open/close quotation marks, then weird things like this could happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution. i had to replace the special characters with their corresponding entity number as per

http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html

Comment: So, one way or the other it was to do with how git perceives the double quote.

Comment: Hyphens (at least) shouldn't need entity replacement, it's quite likely you've got an em-dash or en-dash instead of a regular ASCII hyphen there.